# How do I detect browsers on mobile or on desktop?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

When I presume that a css media query with `max-width: 768px` can make my web page responsive to fit a mobile device. However, iPhone X and later still load the desktop version, because recent phones have even higher resolution than an old desktop.

How do I detect a mobile device not relying on the screen resolution, with Vanilla javascript, pure HTML and CSS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

Comment: Did you forget to set the viewport settings? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

Pixels don't actually work based on the real density of the screen. The pixels we use are [Density independance](https://www.material.io/design/layout/pixel-density.html#density-independence) and the get scalated depending on the screen. If you follow up the media query [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/) uses you can see they actually set it as *max-width: 575.98px* for mobile devices.

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { ... }

// Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px)
@media (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, less than 992px)
@media (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, less than 1200px)
@media (max-width: 1199.98px) { ... }
```